# How can I code WordPress plugin software updates?

Tags: php, wordpress, software-update

This question is probably suitable for all software updating. How does software updating normally work? I have developed a WordPress plugin and now I want to code the updating module. The plugin checks for new updates and if an update is available, the user is notified.

The easiest part is done. A hook to check for new updates is up and running and if a new version available, a notification is shown to the users.

Now comes the hardest part. The new version of the plugin is hosted in my server. Should I need to replace all the files with the new files or only the updated part. I will have a new version as a ZIP file. How can I implement this in WordPress?

Comment: Is your plugin open-source? If so, just submit it to the WP Subversion repository, I think updates are done automatically from that. If this is closed source, look at the WP core code for this, and modify it for your requirements.

Comment: My plugin is closed source

Comment: @halfer Could you please tell me which core file I have to edit

Comment: I don't know without looking at it, you'll need to do some research. Find the svn/git repo for WP, or download a copy and look through that. Also, have you searched for "Wordpress plugin update system" in a search engine?

Comment: Thanks for the keyword you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the question is in *[Automatic Updates For Private And Commercial Plugins](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/)*.

Comment: While maybe an answer, SO aims to provide answers, not links (which potentially might go offline) to answers.

Comment: The link still works, but can you [summarise in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20933845/edit) before the link breaks? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be [uploading your plugin to the WordPress repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/).

WordPress then tells your users about any updates and allows auto updating. Hosting it yourself is not a good way to do things.

Comment: It is a very good way if you develop plugins that are not intended to be publicly available